# Surface Intersections with OPEN CASCADE

Tags: c++, intersection, surface, opencascade

I've a problem about the intersection between two surfaces.
The first is trimmed while the second is untrimmed.

I use the `BRepAlgoAPI_Section` to intersect the two surfaces and obtain the intersection edges (in my case only one):

This is my code, here I make the intersection:

```
TopoDS_Face trimface, face;

BRepAlgoAPI_Section ffsect( trimface, face, Standard_True);
ffsect.Approximation(Standard_True);
ffsect.Build();
```

Here I iterate between the section edges. For each edge I create a `TopoDS_Edge` to put on screen.

```
Standard_Real pFirst, pLast;    

TopTools_ListOfShape edges = ffsect.SectionEdges();

TopTools_ListIteratorOfListOfShape eIter(edges);
while ( eIter.More() ) {

    // For each edge I create a TopoDS_Edge object and I put it on screen   
    TopoDS_Edge edge = TopoDS::Edge(eIter.Value());         
    Handle(AIS_Shape) anAisEdge;
    anAisEdge = new AIS_Shape(edge);
    anAisEdge->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_RED);
    anAisEdge->SetWidth(2.0);
    // get my Ais_InteractiveContext
    myOccView->getContext()->Display(anAisEdge);

    // Create a Geom_BSplineCurve from edge
    Handle(Geom_BSplineCurve) myCurve =     Handle(Geom_BSplineCurve)::DownCast(BRep_Tool::Curve(edge, pFirst, pLast));

    // Now create a TopoDS_Edge from my curve 
    TopoDS_Edge edge2 = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(myCurve);
    Handle(AIS_Shape) anAisEdge2;
    anAisEdge2 = new AIS_Shape(edge2);
    anAisEdge2->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_RED);
    anAisEdge2->SetWidth(2.0);
    myOccView->getContext()->Display(anAisEdge2);

    eIter.Next();
}
```

If I check separately the display on screen of `anAisEdge` and `anAisEdge2` I obtain two different results. I don't understand why.
In the two images on top the first display while down the second one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the OCC documentation for the [BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge](https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.1.0/refman/html/class_b_rep_builder_a_p_i___make_edge.html) class is stated that "If the curve is a trimmed curve the basis curve is used". In this case, I think you should directly specify the required parameter values of the curve in the BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge constructor.